# SSH en Subprocess Python3

Tags: python, ssh

Me gustaría conectarme a un dispositivo de red como un router Cisco a través de Python, quiero usar Subprocess pero cuando es un dispositivo nuevo o la clave RSA ha sido sustituida me preguntan si quiero continuar:

```
The authenticity of host '192.168.10.129 (192.168.10.129)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? no
Host key verification failed.
```

Normalmente aparece ese mensaje, pero con esta línea de código:

```
subprocess.run(['ssh',v_user+'@'+v_ip])
```

Dicho mensaje no aparece y no puedo introducir un yes o no.

Comment: Creo Creo deria bueno que agregaras el código completo para así comprender mejor que es lo que pasa

Comment: El código de atrás no tiene que ver mucho con la conexión SSH, simplemente se obtiene el valor del usuario y la IP a través de un Dataframe.

Comment: Básicamente me gustaría ejecutar un SSH desde python como si fuese ejecutado desde una terminal.